# When using clearmake, MAKEFILE_LIST is an empty list

Tags: makefile, clearcase

When I use `clearmake -C gnu` on makefiles that use the `MAKEFILE_LIST` variable, `MAKEFILE_LIST` is empty. But when I use regular GNU make on the same makefiles, `MAKEFILE_LIST` is a list of file paths and names (as it should be).

To see what `MAKEFILE_LIST` is equal to, I'm using `$(info $$MAKEFILE_LIST is [${MAKEFILE_LIST}])`. There are no spaces in any of the file names, so I know that's not causing any problems, and the ClearCase manual lists some features of GNU make that `clearmake` does not support, but `MAKEFILE_LIST` is not among those features.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with `clearmake` and `MAKEFILE_LIST`? If so, were you able to fix it and how?

Answer (score 2):

Had to look up the MAKEFILE_LIST macro to see what it did. And yes, this isn't something that clearmake currently supports. It's also not something listed as explicitly not supported.

I used the sample make snippet at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html to confirm the lack.

I can't categorize this as a defect, so the best bet would be to avoid the middleman and enter the RFE in the Developerworks RFE community at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

If at all possible, can you please provide a "business justification" in Manager-Speak (Dollars lost/Man hours needed to work around not having the capability)? Like every other non-startup development shop, developer time is at a premium, so it's important to put the impact in.

I can't say that you'll get the answer you want, but you should get a response.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into submitting an RFE. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written looks pretty clear that it's not supported; just because it's not listed in the manual doesn't mean that they support it.  That manual might have just not been updated.  However, `MAKEFILE_LIST` was added in GNU make 3.80 which was released in 2002.  Pretty lame if they don't indeed support it.

For the amount of $$ you're paying for ClearCase, I would recommend you contact their support and ask them directly rather than trying to get answers from StackOverflow :).

In any event if you want answers from people who use ClearCase I suggest you add that, or at the very least clearmake, to your list of tags.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in "[Rational ClearCase: `clearmake -C gnu` and GNUmake diferences.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC39003)", [`clearmake`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearmake.htm) is *not* `gmake`.

And [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014674585#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014674607) makes it clear that "base ClearCase" isn't exactly actively developed (though it is still very much maintained with ClearCase 9.x, as shown in this recent [`clearmake` output format](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21981996)).

`MAKEFILE_LIST` is not mentioned in "[`env_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/env_ccase.htm)" (which includes standard UNIX and Linux EVs that are particularly important for ClearCase and MultiSite), and I never had the occasion of using it.

Comment: that thread is 5 years old. And post dates the release of Automatic views and a few other features. So, it isn't dead yet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGFXGwHsD_A

Comment: Also, the canonical reference for clearmake's GNU make emulation would be the makefile_gnu man/infocenter page.

Comment: @BrianCowan Sure but the point stands: The development of ClearCase isn't exactly thriving anymore.

Comment: That could be said about almost every large software package. It isn't exciting or the stuff of press releases... But then neither is plumbing. Infrastructure is something you don't WANT to be exciting, because that usually means something failed catastrophically.

Comment: @brian I agree, for having done ClearCase administration from 2002 to 2011, I can attest to the remarkable stability of that product.